# How can I use fs.read() in Node js

Tags: node.js, filestream, fs

I try to use Nodejs fs.read Method in Mac OS. However it doesn't work..
I use below source code

```
    var fs = require('fs');
    fs.open('helloworld.txt', 'r', function(err, fd) {
        fs.fstat(fd, function(err, stats) {

            var bufferSize=stats.size  ,
                chunkSize=512,
                buffer=new Buffer(bufferSize),
                bytesRead = 0;

            while (bytesRead < bufferSize) {
                if ((bytesRead + chunkSize) > bufferSize) {
                    chunkSize = (bufferSize - bytesRead);
                }

                fs.read(fd, buffer, bytesRead, chunkSize, bytesRead, testCallback);
                bytesRead += chunkSize;
            }
            console.log(buffer.toString('utf8'));
        });
        fs.close(fd);
    });

    var testCallback = function(err, bytesRead, buffer){
        console.log('err : ' +  err);
    };
```

Actually, I use some example in stackoverflow.

When I execute the source,

```
err : Error: EBADF, read
```

this err is returned.

However if I use readFile method, it works well.

```
    fs.readFile('helloworld.txt', function (err, data) {
       if (err) throw err;    
       console.log(data.toString('utf8'));
    });
```

result is

```
Hello World!
```

Of course, it's same file.

Please, let me know what the problem is.

Thank you.

Comment: The fact that you're closing the file in `open`'s callback is kind of strange.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is not int the functions you are using, but in the way you are using them.

All those fs.* functions you are using are asynchronous, that means they run in parallel. So, when you run fs.close, the others have not finished yet.

You should close it inside the fs.stat block:

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.open('helloworld.txt', 'r', function(err, fd) {
    fs.fstat(fd, function(err, stats) {

        var bufferSize=stats.size  ,
            chunkSize=512,
            buffer=new Buffer(bufferSize),
            bytesRead = 0;

        while (bytesRead < bufferSize) {
            if ((bytesRead + chunkSize) > bufferSize) {
                chunkSize = (bufferSize - bytesRead);
            }

            fs.read(fd, buffer, bytesRead, chunkSize, bytesRead, testCallback);
            bytesRead += chunkSize;
        }
        console.log(buffer.toString('utf8'));
        fs.close(fd);
    });
});

var testCallback = function(err, bytesRead, buffer){
    console.log('err : ' +  err);
};
```

Comment: This is incorrect. The line `console.log(buffer.toString('utf8'));` does not wait for the asynchronous call to `fs.read`, so it is not guaranteed to work. Testing the code, it often fails and spits out gibberish because the `buffer` has not had all the file bytes read into it. Any use of `buffer` needs to happen inside `testCallback`, although in this case, we have a while loop of calls to `fs.read` so we need a better way to figure out when *all* the calls the `fs.read` have finished.

Answer (score 0):

`fs.read` and `fs.fstat` are async functions.

And just after calling, `fstat`, you are closing the file (`fs.close(fd);`).

That could be the reason for this error.

Answer (score 0):

The error in the code is that you are currently using asynchronus functions in your application. Which simply means that before performing the first operation the other one starts in parallel i.e. `fs.close()` closes your file before performing the operation. You can simple replace them with synchronus functions provided by the same `fs` module from node.js.